# importing different types of date/time values

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I have a csv file where date/time is written as 20181014042709 which means 2018-10-14 04:27:09

I tried to use SET datestyle command but I didn't find anything that suited.

Is there a way to properly import this data type to a timestamp column?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Convert it to a recognized format before you import.
2. Import into staging table where the column is `varchar` and then transform the string using [to_timestamp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-formatting.html) like:

```
select to_timestamp('20181014042709', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');
  to_timestamp      
------------------------
 2018-10-14 04:27:09-07

--The -07 is because:
show timezone;
  TimeZone  
------------
 US/Pacific
```

when moving the data to final table.

The patterns in  format string 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' are explained in the link I provided above in section *Table 9.26. Template Patterns for Date/Time Formatting*.